# How to use UTC date string as recharts axis and distribute it evenly

Tags: reactjs, recharts

My source of data looks like this:

```
const data = [
    { dataora: "2019-10-20T04:00:00Z", valore: -0.04 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-20T05:00:00Z", valore: -0.03 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-20T06:00:00Z", valore: -0.03 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-20T07:00:00Z", valore: -0.03 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-21T10:00:00Z", valore: -0.04 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-21T23:00:00Z", valore: -0.04 },
    { dataora: "2019-10-22T00:00:00Z", valore: -0.04 }
  ];
```

My `recharts` component looks like this:

```
<LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="valore" stroke="black" strokeWidth={2} dot={false} />
  <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" />
  <XAxis
    dataKey={'dataora'}
    tickFormatter={dateFormatter}
  />
  <YAxis />
</LineChart>
```

`dateFormatter` looks like this:

```
const dateFormatter = date => {
  // return moment(date).unix();
  return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm');
};
```

Usually I have a data entry every other hour, but `2019-10-21` has only two values for the whole day, now I'd like to show also the missing hours in my graph. In other data entries I may get different time gap so I can't set the tick interval manually.. I just need the date field to be distributed evenly on the XAxis.

I tried to change the `tickFormatter` to return the date in Unix epoch seconds and use the below props..

`scale="time" type="number" domain={[dateFormatter(data[0].dataora), dateFormatter(data[1].dataora)]}`

but the XAxis dissapeared along with the data line.
Is there any way to "fill in" those date blanks?

[A codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-pine-mtdxn)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[answering myself here]

It turns out that I had to process the input data beforehand since recharts does not have anything that allows me to teach him *how* to read my input data.
So I converted my date field to epoch.

```
data.forEach(d => {
  d.dataora = moment(d.dataora).valueOf(); // date -> epoch
});
```

And then I can use the date field type as a number and set the domain etc.

```
<XAxis 
  dataKey={'dataora'}
  domain={[data[0].dataora, data[data.length - 1].dataora]}
  scale="time"
  type="number"
  tickFormatter={DateFormatter} />
```

I'm not really happy with this solution because it requires me to actually process all the data before rendering the chart. I haven't tried it with large size data (thousands of entries or more) yet but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: even if you had a way to "teach" recharts how to process the data, then you would push preprocessing calculations to in the charts calculations, there is no way around it

Comment: I figured if it's smart enough it should process one entry at a time, say it gets 1, then it gets 3, so when processing 3 it goes: ok lemme put a blank before putting 3

Comment: switching to numeric date for correct range and format for tooltip. It's little ridiculous compared to other charts. But @leverglowh your solution works. Thanks.